Country absense check for Spanish long term residence permit application
One of the requirements for extending the residence permit in an EU country (Spain) is not to be absent from the country for more than 6 months in each year. Also, one of the conditions for obtaining a long-term residence permit after 5 years of legal residence in the country is not to be absent for 10 months within 5 years.
Question: Does the migration office check compliance with these deadlines only with the entry/exit stamps in the passport? Or is it possible that they also check in the unified electronic database of Schengen borders?
